# factory_bot does not support initialize_with keyword arguments

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

Given the following class:

```
class URL
  attr_reader :description
  attr_reader :url

  def initialize(description:, url:)
  end
end
```

and the following factory bot definition:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :url, class: URL do
    description { 'test_description' }
    url { 'test_url' }
   
    initialize_with { new(description: description, url: url) }
  end
end
```

It raises the exception:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0; required keywords: description, url)
```

Also tried: `initialize_with { new(**attributes) }` with the same outcome.

Running with: `factory_bot 6.2.1` and `ruby 3.0.4`

Any insights on why this happening? Or it is something unsupported?

Comment: I am unable to recreate this issue. [Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/FactoryBotinitializewith#). Can you please provide a full stacktrace, maybe that will help?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I found the issue, please try your example with gem 'activesupport', '~> 5.2'.

Comment: I would not recommend ruby 3 with rails 5.2. Nor would others: https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html

Comment: That has indeed solved part of the problem. But now I am running into another because my class inherits from `Dry::Struct`
[Example](https://replit.com/@NunoGomes5/FactoryBotinitializewith#main.rb)
The dry-struct gem is the available latest version.

Comment: Your issue is that `Dry::Struct` defines `::new` (https://github.com/dry-rb/dry-struct/blob/main/lib/dry/struct/class_interface.rb#L249) so when you call `URL.new` this method is being called. This in turn calls `struct.__send__(:initialize, attributes)` (notice attributes are not splatted) this causes your error. That being said given your new information the custom initialize is not needed. If you remove it completely everything works as expected [Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/FactoryBotinitializewith-DRY#main.rb)

Answer (score 0):

In this class initialize method, where we have assigned the instance variables?,

As you are using keyword argument for initialize method of the URL class, so the parameters need to be defined seperately.

like this:

```
class URL
  attr_reader :description
  attr_reader :url

  def initialize(description:, url:)
    @description = description
    @url = url
  end
end
```

Comment: It does not matter. The error happens before doing anything with the initialized parameters. The actual problem has already been pointed out by
engineersmnky in the comments.